# C++ Прочитать содержание папки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Всем привет, надо прочитать содержание папки, точнее прочитать имя всех файлов которые есть в папке, и запушить их в переменную с типом `vector<wstring>`.

Я сделал так:

```
vector<wstring> readFolder(LPWSTR path) {
    vector<wstring> names;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;
    hf = FindFirstFile((LPCTSTR)path, &FindFileData);

    if (hf != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        do
        {
            names.push_back((wstring)FindFileData.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    return names;
}
```

НО, если выбрать самую папку с названием test, то результат таков:

[image: Пример]

Comment: Щас бы -1 ставить...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Цикл do делается один раз, потому в векторе только один элемент. Path должен быть, что то типа test\\*, где * это маска для искомых файлов (например *_??.bmp или просто *.bmp для всех файлов bmp).